# Finding .exe path of Windows store app from its "ID"

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have an app ID e.g., "shell:AppsFolder\SpotifyAB.SpotifyMusic_zpdnekdrzrea0!Spotify". (Sorry, don't know / can't find what's name of this so I call it app ID.)

When this is executed, e.g., System.Diagnostics.Process.Start in .NET, the following .exe is started "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\SpotifyAB.SpotifyMusic_1.140.508.0_x86__zpdnekdrzrea0\spotify.exe".

Is there a way to find .exe files based on 'app ID'? [For apps that are installed on the machine.)
I'm fine with any way - windows API, .NET way - whatever.

1 way is to monitor what processes start after that app ID is executed but that don't look like a solid design.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to use the [PackageManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager?view=winrt-19041) class?

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz - No, let me check it. Thanks!